# is it possible to use colspan in float number in html table?

Tags: html, html-table

how can i get it If I have two rows first row has two columns and second row has three columns and I want to give 1.5 colspan to first row. How is it possible to use colspan without using div.

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Is the goal to achieve the screenshot above (a predetermined number of columns) or do you want this to work regardless of the number of columns? For the latter, I would think specifying the width as percentages would be easiest.

Comment: I'd argue that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/400248). The right solution could very well be to not use tables for this at all, because you're going to have to get hacky. Why use tables if you're going to have to "trick" them to behave as *not* tables? Care to elaborate why you're avoiding divs...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  padding: 4px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

table td:empty {
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td colspan="2">4</td>
    <td colspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad to help. If is ok, please accept this as the answer.